# How do i get description and title of facebook pages, users in php?

Tags: php, facebook, file-get-contents

I am using PHP function `get_meta_tags` to get several info from the different websites like `description`. When it comes to Facebook it doesn't show any type of description. It gives description for Facebook fan page but not for any users profile page.

```
$tags = get_meta_tags('https://www.facebook.com/zuck?fref=ts');

echo $tags['og:description'];
```

I am also facing problems for getting title of Facebook pages as well as users profile page using following script:

```
$str = file_get_contents('https://www.facebook.com/zuck?fref=ts');

if(strlen($str)>0){

    preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/",$str,$title);

    return $title[1];

}
```

Correct title as well as description:

[image: Correct Response (Image Preview)]

Facebook profile page title as well as description:

[image: Wrong Response (Image Preview)]

Comment: Please use the Stack Overflow image uploader, otherwise your screenshots won't work in SSL mode. I've fixed them for you in this post.

Answer (score 1):

You need an Access Token in order to get details of a User profile.

Information about Access Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Answer (score 0):

To get Faxcebook page details use below method

http://graph.facebook.com/pageid
      or
 http://graph.facebook.com/pageusername

Example http://graph.facebook.com/38282497425

The output will be in json format.then use any json decxoding methods .